# Odoo Tab Index is not working for Wizard Buttons

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11, tabindex

I have one `Print` button in my Wizard.I can focus on other fields by using `tab`.But for the `Print` button it is not possible.I want to focus to `Print` button and when I click `Enter` , I need to press the button.
I tried like this :

**First Try**

> XML

```
        <group>
          <field name = "xn_barcode" />
          <field name = "price"/>
          <button name="generate" tabindex="1" type="object" string="Print"/>
        </group>
        <footer>
          <button name="generate" tabindex="1" type="object" string="Print"/>
        </footer>
```

My button name is `generate` I tried by using `tabindex` attribute.
And I tried placing this button inside `group` and `footer`.

**Second Try**(Also mentioned for `EasyOdoo`'s reply)

I refered a wizard in Account Invoice.(`account.account_invoice_confirm_view`) (Invoice Tree>Action>Confirm Draft Invoice) There it is working.What I find out while comparing is that, that wizard does not have any field in it.(Only `<p>` tag with some data found in that wizard) And I tried my wizard with no fields in it and it is working.But I want fields in my wizzard.What to do?I think its an odoo issue.

> Odoo's Confirm Draft Invoices Wizard's Code

```
<form string="Confirm Draft Invoices">
     <p class="oe_grey">
      Once draft invoices are confirmed, you will not be able
      to modify them. The invoices will receive a unique
      number and journal items will be created in your chart
      of accounts.
      </p>
      <footer>
         <button string="Confirm Invoices" name="invoice_confirm" type="object" default_focus="1" class="btn-primary"/>
         <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
      </footer>
 </form>
```

Please Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```xml
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
        <sheet>
            <group>
              <field name = "xn_barcode" />
              <field name = "price"/>
            </group>
        </sheet>
        <footer>
           <button name="generate" type="object" string="Print"/>
           <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel"/>
        </footer>
    </form>
</field>
```

Result should look like this:

[image: You should see a result looks like this]

Comment: I tried like this:
`<button class="btn-primary" tabindex="0" name="generate" id ="xn_print_btn" type="object" string="Print" />` and 

`<button class="btn-primary" name="generate" id ="xn_print_btn" type="object" string="Print" />`

But its not working.What I want is that when we press `Tab` ,I should be able to select that `generate` button. Now its not focusing to `generate` button no matter how many times I press the `tab` .

Comment: Are you sure the class is applied is the button color blue?!! see my updates and did you have result like mine

Comment: I tried like this,and its color changes to blue as you mentioned.But I am  not able to navigate to that button using Tab key.I tried like this:


                  `<button name="generate" class="btn-primary" type="object" string="Print"/>`




  `<button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel"/>`

Comment: New Update: I refered a wizard in Account Invoice.(account.account_invoice_confirm_view) (Invoice Tree>Action>Confirm Draft Invoice) There it is working.What I find out while comparing is that that wizard does not have any field in it.(Only `<p>` tag with some data found in that wizard) And I tried my wizard with no fields in it and it is working.But I want fields in my wizzard.What to do?I think its an odoo issue.